What makes this question about sexuality and social determinants of gender about philosophy?
See Is the notion that queer identities and sexuality are innate incompatible with the view that genders are socially molded?
This seems like a science question question to me (perhaps biology, genetics, sociology). What does philosophy add to the analysis of whether these notions are incompatible?

If the question is about whether they are conceptually compatible, then it has a philosophical dimension.

In a multidisciplinary culture why would that question be denied to philosophy? (Disciplines are the tools of culture.)

The site has both a sociology tag and a philosophy of biology tag.
Gender and sexuality are central topics in well-established fields of philosophy, such as feminist philosophy and queer theory.
Sociology and philosophy have arguably long had an overlap. Some of the founders of sociology such as Marx and Weber created the field by philosophically arguing why a distinct type of epistemology was necessary to study “social phenomena”.

So, what constitutes philosophy is itself quite a philosophical question, so much in fact, there is a body of emerging philosophical literature called metaphilosophy. One of the widely held misconceptions, according to my pluralist views on philosophy, is that philosophy exists as entirely distinct from other disciplines: That's not philosophy, that's science! That's not philosophy, that's math! That's not philosophy, that's law!
A more sophisticated way of looking at it, is that philosophy comprises a set of practices and a vocabulary applied to conceptual analysis. For me in particular, that often means applying the philosophy of language in a way that is consistent with the Linguistic Turn. The results of that practice is seeing the foundation of all disciplines outside of philosophy as resting on a certain domain-specific metaphysics.
Descartes famously referred to such an idea that there are ideas that had before ideas are discussed as "first-principles". This often means looking at worldviews that theories are seated in, or presuppositions that are held to make sense of arguments within a discipline. As an example, a Christian theologian might argue that the resurrection of Jesus of Nazareth is a miracle beyond the rules of science. That begs the question, what exactly is a miracle (SEP)?
More relevant to your question, what exactly is sexuality? identity? Identity politics? There are the slogans you might here on TikTok, but then there is a deep analysis of language and meaning that takes a look at religion, science, politics, and history as a guide for understanding it. You say, this seems like a science question, but then, as anyone who studies the philosophy of science is aware of, there is Popper's question of demarcation asking, what exactly is science anyway?
Interestingly, some people reject science! There are philosophers who reject global warming, evolution, and constitutional law. These aren't dumb people; rather they cook up interesting arguments to challenge our first-principles. While I promote a mild scientism, it's an empirical fact that many people reject any hint of scientism. And the place where that happens is in the metaphysics of the arguments. Thus, any issue is amenable to metaphysical analysis and therefore philosophical dispute. Thus, while there are technical questions within a field (for instance, surveying the prevalence of homosexuality in a population), the question of what constitutes a good survey, or what exactly homosexuality is, is open to debate.
